# How manage versions of Android

Tags: android, performance, notifications

I have a question :

I am trying to make an app for Android 3.0.
In my app I use notification like this :

```
android.app.Notification.Builder noti = new 
android.app.Notification.Builder(MyService.this)
.setOngoing(true)
.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.compose))
.setContentText(getString(R.string.details))
.setSmallIcon(icon)   
//.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN)
.setAutoCancel(false)
.setWhen(0L)
.setContentIntent(pIntentPost);     
Notification notif = noti.build();
mNotificationManager.notify(1337, notif);
```

But I have a pb because "noti.build" is not found !

I have tried this :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
MyService.this);
Notification notification = builder.setContentIntent(pIntentPost)
.setSmallIcon(icon).setOngoing(true)
.setTicker(getString(R.string.compose))
.setWhen(0L)
.setAutoCancel(false).setContentTitle(getString(R.string.compose))
.setContentText(getString(R.string.details))
.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN).build();
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I manage diferent version of android in my app ? I have to import specific library ? I don't understand...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're building with the latest SDK versions, you can use the following as an example:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    // do Notification.Builder code for devices running 3.0 API or greater
} else {
    // do other code for devices running < 3.0 API
}
```

Comment: Ok but How I remove errrors in my code concerning noti.build(); and .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN) I have these configuration : Target API target=android-11 and   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="18" /> What's wrong ?

Comment: Which SDK version are you using to compile? If you use an SDK version which contains these methods, the lint error should go away as long as you protect it with the code I mentioned. Otherwise, if for some reason lint still gives a problem, there's a way to configure Eclipse (assuming you're using Eclipse) that will still allow it to compile in this fashion.

Comment: I was in Target API target=android-11 and put it on Target API target=android-17 It compiles thxs ! I hope all is ok !